# Representing a labeled image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Say that we have divided some image into two clusters. And, based on some criteria, we have assigned some pixels to cluster `1` and the other pixels to cluster `2`.

In this case, we will have an image holding the values of clusters, that is, `1` and `2`. But, when we want to show such image, we will notice that it doesn't look like the original image, especially that the pixels now hold the values of the clusters.

How can we represent such labeled image to look like the original image. That is, to give a meaningful representation in `MATLAB`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must keep the shape of a rectangle to display an image. 
assuming Cluster is the same size as image.

```
img(Cluster==2) = 0; % set 0 all cluseter 2 pixels
imshow (img); % will display only pixel in cluseter 1
```